# Hide/Show All Windows and Restore Z-Order

Tags: c++, windows, api

I'm working on an app that hide and shows all windows on the desktop at the push of a button to get them out of the way.  The problem is that when I show them, they are not in the proper Zorder as when I hid them.  Is there any way to get the Zorder and show it in the proper order?  I'm using Win7 64.  I'm using this to hide/show:

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);    // hide
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNA);  // show
```

Comment: I just tried it with my browser in front, but then when I did again, a totally different window was.

Comment: Weird, I just tried it again with my app, and it put the correct window on top.  Maybe it does work sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these functions to keep the z-order

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Although a better way is to minimize the windows (look for tab windows only). You would have to keep track of which window needs to be restored with `SW_MAXIMIZE` and which window needs to be restored with `SW_RESTORE`. You can use `GetWindowPlacement` to examine window's visibility.

Comment: Do you think adding SWP_NOREPOSITION to the flags would be also be helpful?

Comment: I am not familiar with that. It might be helpful. What problems are there?

Comment: No problems, I just noticed it when looking through the list of flags and thought it wouldn't hurt to have it in there just in case.

Comment: I also wanted to make sure it wouldn't mess anything up.  Here's the description:  
Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.